# When does something get classified as 'undefined' in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and am trying to create an algorithm visualizer on React. I mapped a random array of values (to be sorted) to an array-bar div. In the algorithm, an array captures the indexes being compared which is later used to animate the visualization by changing the heights of the array bars. When running, the visualization seems to work for a second (change color) then gives the error saying 'style' element can't be found. To no avail, I tried excluding the 'state' from the scope of the function think that was where the issue was.

```
merge = () =>{
    const a = this.state.array.slice()
    const animations = SortingAlgorithms.mergeSort(a);
    console.log("merged");
    console.log(this);
    let i =0;
    const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');
    console.log(arrayBars);
    for (i; i<animations.length; i++){
        
        const colorChange = i % 3 !== 2;

        if (colorChange){  //animation to change the color
            const [barOneIdx, barTwoIdx] = animations[i];
            const color = i%3 === 0? 'red':'turquoise';
            const barOne = arrayBars[barOneIdx].style; //crashes here
            const barTwo = arrayBars[barTwoIdx].style; //and here

            setTimeout( ()=>{
                barOne.backgroundColor = color;
                barTwo.backgroundColor = color;
            }, i*5);
        }else{           //animation to change the height of array bar to sort
            setTimeout(()=>{
                const [barOneIdx, newHeight] = animations[i];
                const barOne = arrayBars[barOneIdx].style;
                barOne.height = `${newHeight}px`;
            }, i*5);
        }
    }
}
```

the render function where the array bars are mapped to an array

```
    

<div className="array-container">
            {array.map((value, idx)=>(

                <div
                className="array-bar"
                key={idx}
                style={{height: `${value}px`}}>
                </div>

            ))}
            <button onClick={()=>this.resetArray()} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2">reset Array</button>
            <button onClick={this.merge} className="merge">merge</button>
            <button onClick={()=>this.bubble()} className="bubble">bubble sort</button>
            <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2" onClick={this.quickSort} >quick sort</button>
         

    </div>
```

[error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6pCS.jpg)

Comment: If `arrayBars[barOneIdx]` doesn't exist, accessing `arrayBars[barOneIdx].style` will blow up. That's most likely what's happening here: `arrayBars[barOneIdx]` and/or `arrayBars[barTwoIdx]` are not what you think they are.